# How to align the ui for button?

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-button

I need to align the UI for a button, which I posted. I am not sure how to use `Button` or `ImageButton`. How do I align the image and text in a button?

[image]

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnGroupDelete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_buttonselector"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/delete"
                    android:src="@drawable/ox_icn_delete" />
```

Comment: image view or image button is ok but what do you mean by "align ui for button"? if you have layout xml file ,please paste here.

Comment: i need to handle image as well as text(Delete group)

Answer (score 2):

Save image in drawable then use Image button in xml

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/button_image_name" />
```

For state change of button (pressed, focused, default), have a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 1):

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:gravity="right"  <----------
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnGroupDelete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_buttonselector"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/delete"
                    android:src="@drawable/ox_icn_delete" />

Comment: can u give code for the above image i that i need to add text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:text="@string/btntext" />
```